# How to build this json?

Tags: javascript, json

```
[{"username" : "11"},
      {"password" : "test"},
      {"detailorder" : [
        {"id" : "1",
         "qty" : "5"},
        {"id" : "2",
         "qty" : "10"}
      ]}
    ]
```

How di I create above json in javascript? I have very low understanding in json. I reffered to  [How do i build JSON dynamically in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314008/how-do-i-build-json-dynamically-in-javascript). I need to add data dinamically especially for detailorder. But I' stuck from beginning.

I wrote

```
var datajson = [];
```

And i dont know how to what to write next. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Comment: That does not look like valid JSON, since `orderdetail` has multiple objects which are not enclosed in `[]` as an array.

Comment: But anyway, JSON _is_ JavaScript.  If the expression is valid, simply assign it to a variable and you have your object.  `var datajson = [{"username": "11"},{}...]`

Comment: It is indeed - not valid JSON. You can always check with an online validation tool like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: thank you will take alook url given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like:

```
var datajson = [
    { "username" : 11 },
    {"password" : "test"},
    {"orderdetail" : 
        { 
            "id": 1,
            "qty": 25           
        },
        { 
            "id": 2,
            "qty": 10           
        }
    }
];
```

**Added:**

```
var datajson = {};
datajson.username = 11;
datajson.password = "test";
datajson.detilpesanan = [];
datajson.detilpesanan.push({});
datajson.detilpesanan.unshift({});
datajson.detilpesanan[0]["id"] = 1;
datajson.detilpesanan[0]["jumlah"] = 5;
datajson.detilpesanan[1]["id"] = 2;
datajson.detilpesanan[1]["jumlah"] = 10;

console.log( datajson );
```

Comment: I edited json format. I need to able add data dinamically just like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314008/how-do-i-build-json-dynamically-in-javascript answer

Comment: @justmyfreak see added answer

Comment: but it seems that orderdetail in your answer is not valid json. Is it oke to change push and unsift to push([]) and unshift([])

Answer (score 2):

Create the array, assign it to a variable and stringify it.

Here is how:

```
var arr = [
   { username:'11' },
   { password:'test' },
   { detilpesanan: [
       { id:'1',jumlah:'5' },
       { id:'2',jumlah:'10' }
   ]}
];

var json = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest something to make it easier. First, you will need to use jquery, or any other javascript library that provides json parsing and endcoding. Then create that structure as a standard object on javascript. Use jquery ( or whatever javascript library you chose ), to encode it into a JSON string for you.

I have been using JSON format for years now, but I can barely recall the need to write it down myself. Maybe there were instances, but I think I did not use it for the actual implementation.

You can also go to json.org, and download parsers and encoders available.

I hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can see: http://www.json.org/js.html

JSON (Javascrtip Serialization Object) is a serialization object type, so you cant create objects and then serialize this object, like this:

```
        function createPerson()
        {
            var persons = new Array();

            for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                var details = new Array();

                for(k = 0; k<2;k++)
                {
                    var det = new persondetail(k,k*2);
                    details.push(det);
                }

                var p = new person('user'+i,'pdw'+i,details);

                persons.push(p);
            }

                            //-- serialize object, see console output
            console.log(JSON.stringify(persons));

        }

        function person(user, pwd,det)
        {
            this.username = user;
            this.password = pwd;
            this.detilpesanan = det;

        }

        function persondetail(id, jumlah)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.jumlah = jumlah;
        }
```