# Create JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to create a dynamic JSON array in Javascript like that :

```
var jsonData = {
    "Tasks" : [
        {
            "__metadata" : {
                "uri" : "...",
                "type" : "..."
            },
            "ID" : "...",
            "Category" : "..",
            // ...
        },
        {
            "__metadata" : {
                "uri" : "...",
                "type" : "..."
            },
            "ID" : "...",
            "Category" : "..",
            // ...
        },
        // others tasks
    ], "__count" : "2"
};
```

I found how to create a JSON in Javascript but not with this syntax. So what is the good way to create the JSON object with the 'Tasks' array and add items in it ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314008/how-do-i-build-json-dynamically-in-javascript

Comment: your question doesn't make sense. you already have the javascript you want, all you need to call is JSON.stringify() on it and you're done.

Comment: Also the `__count` attribute is redundant. It is already stored within the `Tasks` array.

Comment: This is an object literal, not JSON. Please use the correct terminology, otherwise it is difficult to understand your problem. But I believe the answer is: *you can't*. You can create the initial object with an object literal and then add the data to the array later.

Comment: By "dynamic" It was to generate the task table with a loop. Thank you MrOggy85 for your link, it's usefull !

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
function Metadata(uri,type)
{
    this.uri = uri;
    this.type = type;
}

function Task(metadata, id, category)
{
    this.__metadata = metadata;
    this.ID = id;
    this.Category = category;
}

var tasks = [new Task(new Metadata('foo','bar'), 1, 'blah'), new Task(new Metadata('foo1', 'bar1'), 2, 'blah2')];

document.write(JSON.stringify({"Tasks": tasks, "__count": tasks.length}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create objects with constructors and use the JSON api.

```
var jsonData = {};
jsonData.Tasks = new Array();

var Metadata = function(uri, type){
  this.uri = uri;
  this.type = type;
}

var Task = function (metadata, id, category){
  this.__metadata = metadata;
  this.ID = id;
  this.Category = category;
}

var tasks = jsonData.Tasks;

tasks.push(
  new Task(
    new Metadata("someUri", "someType"),
    1,
    "someCategory")
);
```

jsbin: [working example](http://jsbin.com/uhasof/14/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code and it works :

```
var jsonData = {};
jsonData.Tasks = [];

var count = 0;

for(...) {
    jsonData.Tasks.push({
        "__metadata" : {
            "uri" : "...",
            "type" : "..."
        },
        "ID" : "...",
        "Category" : "...",
    });

    count++;
}

jsonData.__count = count;
```

Thank you for your answers and your reactivity !

Comment: I still recommend you use objects rather than string literals.
I don't know what it means performance whise, but is a lot less error prone.