# Push json data into nested array

Tags: javascript

Im trying to build this array:

---

```
[{
id: "1", name: labels,
periods: [
{id:"1_1", start: "2018-01-05", end: "2018-01-25"},
{id:"1_2", start: "2018-01-28", end: "2018-02-22"},
{id:"1_3", start: "2018-03-03", end: "2018-03-25"}
]
}];
```

---

I have this json data

---

```
labels = ["Workorder 1", ... , "Workorder 10"]
start = ["2019-01-01", ... ,"2019-01-25" ]
end= ["2019-01-10", ... ,"2019-01-25"]
```

---

this is how far I got:

---

```
var arr=[];
for ( var i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
newlab = labels[i];
newid = "id" + [i]; 
newstart = start[i];
newstop = end[i];
arr.push({ id:newid, name:newlab, start:newstart, end:newstop })
};
var data = {data:arr};
console.log(data);
```

---

which has this as output:

---

```
data = [
{id: "id0", name: "Workorder 1", start: "2019-01-01", end: "2019-01-10"},
....
{id: "id9", name: "Workorder 10", start: "2019-11-25", end: "2019-01-14"}
]
```

---

Thank you for any help

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please state your problem clearly.

Comment: Hi @User9023 check if this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314008/how-do-i-build-json-dynamically-in-javascript/4314350).

Comment: what value does `labels` contain, question detail is missing, please provide full detail

Comment: then `name` key is not there in your expected output but you trying to add it in your code

Comment: @NarendraChouhan added to my question

Comment: @User9023 please provide full original JSON and your expected JSON

Comment: @User9023 I have answered your question please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will Work For you, Try this

```js
var labels = ["Workorder 1", "Workorder 10"]
var start = ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-25"]
var end = ["2019-01-10", "2019-01-25"]

var obj = {}
var finalArray = []
for (var i = 1; i <= start.length; i++) {
    var first = { id: i, name: 'labels' }
    obj = { ...obj, ...first }
    var periods = { id: i + '_' + i, name: labels[i - 1], start: start[i - 1], end: end[i - 1] }
    if (obj.periods) {
        obj.periods.push(periods)
    } else {
        obj.periods = [periods]
    }
    finalArray.push(obj)
}

var data = { data: finalArray };
console.log("finalOutput.............",data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let labels="test_string",start = [],end=[],arr=[];
var arr=[],periods =[];
for ( var i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
obj = {};
obj.id= "1", obj.name= "labels"
newlab = labels[i];
newid = [i] + "_" + [i];
newstart = start[i];
newstop = end[i];
periods.push({ id:newid, name:newlab, start:newstart, end:newstop })
obj.periods = periods;
arr.push(obj)
};
let data = {data:arr};
console.log(data);
```

Comment: You can check it in browser or in REPL mode.